# Persistent Connections with MONGOOSE - a good idea?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've made an application enviroment using mongoose and some other stuff which is useful in a nodejs environment.
There I have a constructor defined which setup the persistene for each component.
Then I thougt (and already wrote some working stuff) is it a good idea to hold the connection persistent to prevent reconnections a lot of times.
This is working well (at the moment) but there are two things where I cant find an answear for...

**1) Ho can I Handle errors like connection lost (e.g. DB-server goes down)**

```
db.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('MONGO: ERROR');
    // evt is not fired when DB server goes down
});

db.once('disconnect', function callback() {
console.log('MONGO: DISCONNECTED');
    // evt is also not fired when DB server goes down
});
```

**2) Is it a good idea at all to work with a persistent connection which is done on application start 
   and not on any user request?**

All my components extend from my Persistence Layer which establish the connection and initiate the modelName, schemaDefinition etc.

```
Persistence = function(modelName, schemaDefinition, config) {

this.config = config;

if ( typeof (modelName) === 'string' && schemaDefinition instanceof Object) {
    this.mongoose = require('mongoose');

    if (this.mongoose.connection.readyState == this.config.settings.DATABASE.disconnected) {
        var con = this.mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + this.config.settings.DATABASE.host + '/' + this.config.settings.DATABASE.collection);
    }

        this.modelName = modelName;
    this.schemaDefinition = schemaDefinition;

    var db = this.mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('MONGO: FERROR');
    });

    db.once('open', function callback() {
        console.log('MONGO: CONNECTED');
    });

    db.once('disconnect', function callback() {
    console.log('MONGO: CONNECTION lost');
    });
      }
 };
```

Comment: As far as I know, Mongoose use a [connection pool](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection_pools). So, instead of reconnecting mongodb on each request it takes one connection from the pool of reusable connections and then returns it back.

Comment: That's right and found out that there's an option {auto_reconnect:true} wich ensure that application is workin after database was restarted.